# Batch processing of incoming notifications with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, notifications, sendgrid

My app engine app receives notifications from SendGrid for processing email deliveries, opens, etc.  Sendgrid doesn't do much batching of these notifications so I could receive several per second.

I'd like to do batch processing of the incoming notifications, such as processing all of the notifications received in the last minute (my processing includes transactions so I need to combine them to avoid contention).  There seems to be several ways of doing this...

For storing the incoming notifications, I could:

1. add an entity to the datastore or
2. create a pull queue task.

For triggering processing, I could:

1. Run a CRON job every minute (is this a good idea?) or
2. Have the handler that processes the incoming Sendgrid requests trigger processing of notifications but only if the last trigger was more than a minute ago (could store a last trigger date in memcache).

I'd love to hear pros and cons of the above or other approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days, I've come up with an implementation that works pretty well.

For storing incoming notifications, I'm storing the data in a pull queue task.  I didn't know at the time of my question that you can actually store any raw data you want in a task, and the task doesn't have to itself be the execution of a function.  You probably could store the incoming data in the datastore, but then you'd sort of be creating your own pull tasks so you might as well you the pull tasks provided by GAE.

For triggering a worker to process tasks in the pull queue, I came across this excellent blog post about [On-demand Cron Jobs](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/App-Engine-Cookbook-On-demand-Cron-Jobs) by a former GAE developer.  I don't want to repeat that entire post here, but the basic idea is that each time you add a task to the pull queue, you create a worker task (regular push queue) to process tasks in the pull queue.  For the worker task, you add a task name corresponding to a time interval to make sure you only have one worker task in the time interval.  It allows you to get the benefit of 1-minute CRON job but the added performance bonus that it only runs when needed so you don't have a CRON job running when not needed.